# Left Join and only retrieve the latest record

Tags: sql, join

This is only sample case, my original table is more complex.

Table A

```
| SchoolId| ClubId | ChildID|TeacherId|AttendanceDate|IsPresent|
|:------- |:------:| :-----:|:-------:|:------------:|:-------:|
| A       | 1      | 1      |1        |22-MAY-2022   |1        |
| A       | 1      | 2      |1        |22-MAY-2022   |0        |
| A       | 1      | 3      |1        |22-MAY-2022   |1        |
| B       | 2      | 11     |2        |22-MAY-2022   |1        |
| B       | 2      | 22     |2        |22-MAY-2022   |0        |
| B       | 2      | 33     |2        |22-MAY-2022   |0        |
```

Table B

```
|ChildID|TeacherId |CreateOn        |IsPresent|ReasonId |
|:-----:|:-------: |:--------------:|:-------:|:-------:|
|2      |1         |22-MAY-2022     |0        |1        |
|2      |1         |23-MAY-2022     |0        |2        |
|22     |2         |22-MAY-2022     |0        |2        |
|33     |2         |22-MAY-2022     |0        |3        |
```

Table C

```
| ReasonId | ReasonMaster   |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Health         |
| 2        | Social         |
| 3        | Unknown        |
```

I want the left join result like this :

```
| SchoolId| ClubId | ChildID|TeacherId|AttendanceDate|IsPresent|ReasonId |ReasonMaster |
|:------- |:------:| :-----:|:-------:|:------------:|:-------:|:-------:|:------------:
| A       | 1      | 1      |1        |22-MAY-2022   |1        |         |             |
| A       | 1      | 2      |1        |22-MAY-2022   |0        |2        |Social       |
| A       | 1      | 3      |1        |22-MAY-2022   |1        |         |             |
| B       | 2      | 11     |2        |22-MAY-2022   |1        |         |             |
| B       | 2      | 22     |2        |22-MAY-2022   |0        |2        |Social       |
| B       | 2      | 33     |2        |22-MAY-2022   |0        |3        |Unknown      |
```

Here are my cases:

1. I only want to retrieve the latest data from table B based on create on column on the table B to the table A. Because there is a duplicate input by users. for instance in the table B child Id= 2 & Teacher Id=1.
2. I only need to retrieve the the data if the status in the table A, column IsPresent=0
3. There is an additional data from table C which reason master.

Comment: Show what you tried before getting stuck. 
 Did you use a correlated sub-query at any point?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Assuming MS SQL Server

```
--step 1 - Get the latest rec from table B 

;with MaxCreate as ( Select ChildID,TeacherID,Max(CreateOn) as MaxCreateOn
                    from TableB
                    group by ChildID,TeacherID)
,LatestCreate as (select TableB.ChildID, TableB.TeacherId, TableB.CreateOn, TableB.IsPresent, TableB.ReasonId
from TableB
inner join MaxCreate
on TableB.ChildID = MaxCreate.ChildID
and TableB.TeacherId = MaxCreate.TeacherId
and TableB.CreateOn = MaxCreate.MaxCreateOn)

-- Now Join the latest to the other tables


Select 
 TableA.SchoolId
,TableA.ClubId
,TableA.ChildID
,TableA.TeacherId
,TableA.AttendanceDate
,TableA.IsPresent
,LatestCreate.ReasonId
,TableC.ReasonMaster

From 

TableA Left join LatestCreate
on TableA.ChildID = LatestCreate.ChildID
and TableA.TeacherID = LatestCreate.TeacherID

left join TableC
on LatestCreate.ReasonId = TableC.ReasonId
```

Non CTE method

```
Select 
 TableA.SchoolId
,TableA.ClubId
,TableA.ChildID
,TableA.TeacherId
,TableA.AttendanceDate
,TableA.IsPresent
,LatestCreate.ReasonId
,TableC.ReasonMaster

From 
TableB
inner join
( Select ChildID,TeacherID,Max(CreateOn) as MaxCreateOn
                    from TableB
                    group by ChildID,TeacherID) as MaxCreate
on TableB.ChildID = MaxCreate.ChildID
and TableB.TeacherId = MaxCreate.TeacherId
and TableB.CreateOn = MaxCreate.MaxCreateOn

Left join TableA  
on TableA.ChildID = TableB.ChildID
and TableA.TeacherID = TableB.TeacherID

left join TableC
on TableB.ReasonId = TableC.ReasonId
```